# Getting undefined for Field name in reduxform

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have redux form in a class component and for some reason when I console log the formValues I am getting undefined what is the problem?

```
class CreateTeamBox  extends Component{

    handleFormSubmit({name}){
        console.log(name);

      }

    renderError = ({ touched, error}) => {
        if(touched && error) {
            return(
                <div>{error}</div>
            );
        }
    }

    renderInput = ({input, label, type, meta}) => {



        return(
            <div className={styles.formGroup}>
                <label>{label}</label>
                <input  {...input} />
                <div className={styles.errorWrapper}>
                        {this.renderError(meta)}
                </div>

            </div>

        );

    }

    render() {
        const {handleSubmit, error} = this.props ;
        return(

            <div className={styles.createTeamBox}>
                <div className={styles.titleWrapper}>
                    <h2>create team</h2>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.bodyWrapper}>
                        <div className={styles.submitErrorWrapper}>
                            {error ?  <Error error={error} /> : null}   
                        </div>
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
                            <Field name="name" component={this.renderInput} label="name" />
                             <button className={styles.button} type="submit" >create</button>
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>

)
    }
}


const validate = (formValues) => {
    console.log(formValues.name);
    const name = formValues.name;


     const errors = validateForm(name);


    return errors;



}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'createTeamForm',
    validate

})(CreateTeamBox);
```

I have other reduxform in the same given project with different names, is it causing the problem? Im not sure why  it is happening as I havecopied most of the coe from working reduxform in the given project .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default value of `formValues` will be empty object, after enter some data to the field then you can get the value, or you can pass the value by using `initialValues`